# PySpark: Adding A Column To A RowMatrix

Tags: apache-spark, matrix, pyspark

I am presently trying to increment the rank of a `RowMatrix` in PySpark with every iteration in some ML algorithm. I wasn't able to find any methods in [Pyspark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix) that append a column to a `RowMatrix`.

However, I did notice the `BlockMatrix` class has an `add` method, so I attempted to convert my matrices to that class and then use `add`, as evinced below:

```
A = SparkUtils.produce_random_row_matrix(spark_session, A_rows, rank)
B = SparkUtils.produce_random_row_matrix(spark_session, B_rows, rank)

A.toBlockMatrix(rowsPerBlock=A.numRows(), colsPerBlock=A.numCols())
B.toBlockMatrix(rowsPerBlock=B.numRows(), colsPerBlock=B.numCols())

A_new_vector = BlockMatrix(spark_session.parallelize([((0, 0), Matrices.rand(A.numRows(), 1))]))
B_new_vector = BlockMatrix(spark_session.parallelize([((0, 0), Matrices.rand(B.numRows(), 1))]))

A = A.add(A_new_vector)
B = B.add(B_new_vector)
```

However, the code is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'tuple'> into a sub-matrix block tuple
```

I investigated the function producing the message, `_convert_to_matrix_block_tuple`, in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/mllib/linalg/distributed.py), and found that ran the following tests to confirm all the conditions in the `if` statement were met:

```
elem = ((0, 0), Matrices.dense(A.numRows(), 1, 
np.random.rand(A.numRows())))
length_filter = len(elem) == 2
type_filter = isinstance(elem, tuple)

first_type_filter = isinstance(elem[0], tuple)
first_length_filter = len(elem[0]) == 2
second_type_filter = isinstance(elem[1], Matrix)
```

All of vars returned `True`. Would anyone with more experience in PySpark be able to provide some guidance? Thanks.